# check key held using the InputProcessor

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I need to check whether a key is pressed using the InputProcessor. I see various solutions around the net setting a boolean to true once a key is pressed and to false when it is released. This feels more like a hack then a good solution, let me explain.

The static methods `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(int key)` and `Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(int key)` do exactly what they are supposed to do. But when i implement the `InputProcessor` `Interface` I do not get this functionality. I only get:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}
```

These only register once, basically `keyDown == Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(int key)`. Now for each key i want to add functionality i have to create a boolean inside these method. Then I need to make another bunch of if statements in some other method and call that when needed.

So instead of:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.Left) //do stuff ;
    //etc...
    return false;
}
```

I have to do this:

```
boolean leftHold = false;

public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.Left) leftHold = true;
    //etc...
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.Left) leftHold = false;
    //etc...
    return false;
}

public void ProcessingTheInputWeGetFromTheInputPorcessor() //starting to feel ridiculous...
{
    if (leftHold) //Do stuff ;
    //etc..
}

//And call this method each frame on the object:
controlledObject.ProcessingTheInputWeGetFromTheInputPorcessor();
```

So what is the proper solution for detecting key held with the InputProcessor.

Comment: An `InputProcessor` should not store whether a button/key is pressed or not. That's exactly what `Gdx.input.isXXXPressed()` does. If you want to store it yourself for some reason, use a collection to store the currently pressed keycodes instead of individual booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the InputProcessor for that purpose, you use the InputProcessor to immediately process the input, e.g.

```
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    if (keyCode == Keys.Escape) {
        closeGame();
    }
    if (keyCode == Keys.Left) {
        startMovingLeft();
    }
}
```

If you want to continuously check in a loop you just use the static method `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(int key)` e.g.

```
public void loop() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Left)) {
        moveLeft();
    }
}
```

But this is not recommended because you can miss key presses if you press the key in between loops, and certainly not recommended in the render loop because the rate at which you act upon key presses depends on the framerate.

Thanks to noone for helping me improve the answer.

Comment: Not correct. For one time key presses you can use Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(). And especially in loops you shouldn't handle gameplay specific updates via Gdx.input.isKeyPressed because it would be framerate dependent and you can miss inputs. That's exactly where you should use an `InputProcessor` (which should trigger methods like `startMovingLeft` and `stopMovingLeft`, for example.

Comment: That is indeed so, but the op was asking for a way to check if a key was being pressed inside the `ProcessingTheInputWeGetFromTheInputPorcessor()` method which I presumed is called in a loop and not necessarily the render loop but could also be a separate logic loop. Aside from that I stand corrected though.

Comment: Yes, the question itself is "incorrect". The `InputProcessor` itself should process the input when it "arrives" and not buffer it until a `ProcessingTheInput` method is called from outside.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to reflect your comments, I believe it is now correct.